# Redshift sql query fails with assert error

Tags: amazon-redshift

I am getting assert failure when running a select query on this view.

```
dev=# \d+ query_vw
                               View "public.query_vw"
      Column      |            Type             | Modifiers | Storage  | Description
------------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+-------------
 query            | integer                     |           | plain    |
 queue_start_time | timestamp without time zone |           | plain    |
 queue_end_time   | timestamp without time zone |           | plain    |
 queuetime_ms     | bigint                      |           | plain    |
 exec_start_time  | timestamp without time zone |           | plain    |
 exec_end_time    | timestamp without time zone |           | plain    |
 exectime_ms      | bigint                      |           | plain    |
 querytxt         | text                        |           | extended |
View definition:
 SELECT q.query, w.queue_start_time, w.queue_end_time, w.total_queue_time / 1000 AS queuetime_ms, w.exec_start_time, w.exec_end_time, w.total_exec_time / 1000 AS exectime_ms, btrim(q.querytxt::character varying::text) AS querytxt
   FROM stl_query q, stl_wlm_query w
  WHERE q.userid <> 1 AND q.userid <> 100 AND q.query = w.query;
```

Below query is generated by pg_tail utility - I cannot change the way it generates the query. The error seems to be intermittent, any pointers?

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (SELECT
        query,
        queue_start_time,
        queue_end_time,
        queuetime_ms,
        exec_start_time,
        exec_end_time,
        exectime_ms,
        querytxt
    FROM
        query_vw
    ORDER BY
        query DESC LIMIT 5) AS tmp
ORDER BY
    query ASC;

ERROR:  Assert
DETAIL:
  -----------------------------------------------
  error:  Assert
  code:      1000
  context:   mod == -1 && size == 0 - type: 1114, mod: 0, size: 0
  query:     7801463
  location:  pg_utils.cpp:1335
  process:   padbmaster [pid=15775]
  -----------------------------------------------
```

Comment: It seems to be claiming that the problem is within `pg_utils`, rather than Redshift. Have you tried running the query in a different SQL client (eg DbVisualizer, or even the Query Editor in the Redshift console)? Perhaps it is returning too much data for your app to handle.

Comment: Yes, ran the same query in DBeaver UI and it throws the same error there as well.

Comment: If multiple clients are giving the same error, the the cause is something within Redshift. To identify what might be causing it, try to simplify/modify the query until the error goes away. For example, remove the `ORDER BY`, then try just the inner query, etc.

Comment: The query works when running just the inner query and other combinations, but the problem is that the query cannot be changed as its generated by the utility.

Comment: It would be worth finding which element "breaks" the query. Is it the `ORDER BY`? Is it merely placing it within a sub-query? Then, compare `EXPLAIN` plans between the query that works and the query that does not work. Try to see what is causing the problem. It _might_ be solved by making the table more efficient (eg distribution and sort keys). Worst case, you might need to create a table with the VIEW data instead of using the View itself.